# Inserting a text field into a system tray popup menu C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, popupmenu

[image]

I want to achieve such a popup menu as shown in the picture,
is there a native WINAPI feature? I couldnt find one.
Ive only found the ModifyMenu function which lets me to draw the menu myself
with MF_OWNERDRAW I assume this is also what f.e. Steam is using to achieve their darkgray popup menus?

Comment: Looks like ownerdraw to me.

Comment: i just checked the app i screenshoted, its a .net application and is using a ToolStripTextBox so I cant do that. What would be the best approach to achieve such a thing? Ive checked this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2080/Transparent-Menu which mentions a superclassing technique. is that the way to go if i want to fully customize the contextmenu?

Comment: As stated you need [owner drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms647558(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items), here is an [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsOwnerDrawnMenu-a9888b0c)

Comment: Or, simply don't display a standard popup menu to begin with. You can't put a real text box on a real menu, and owner-drawing a fully functional text box is a lot of work with little benefit. Create a custom window that *looks* like a popup menu, put whatever you want on it, and then display it where needed. Nothing says a tray icon has to popup a real menu. It just has to react to the user's clicks in a manner that the user expects (left-click = do action, right-click = show a menu).

Comment: With .NET you apparently can :D But anyways, I also thought about that, only thing I would need to fix (as long its possible) is to not make the selfdrawn popup window transparent on the taskbar